# Generating JPA entities from existing database vs Security

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I need to migrate my application from JDBC programing model to use Hibernate. As part of this I would like to use the Annotation based configuration of hibernate. For this I want to generate `JPA` entities from database. I know how to do this(Using Eclipse Link), but How can I ensure the data is secured when I create `JPA` entities from my `IDE(Eclipse)`? Because `Ecplise Link` is a third party tool, Is there some extra configuration to prevent my database access.

Is there a way achieve this through coding?

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the model from an empty database which contains the structure only and no data.

Comment: But my datdabase is not empty.